# High virtual memory and swap usage on mavericks

Tags: macos

I'm really unsure why the Swap used is that high..

I'm not running anything now except for Firefox and there's still something causing that memory pressure.

[image]

Is it normal(I doubt so)? If not, how can I solve it?

Comment: There is not much pressure here as the graph is green and only has a height of a small part of the possible height. The swap is small (note it is MB not GB). The next step is to look at Real Memory in Activity Monitor

Comment: Is there a process called "system-stats" running? It may be consuming a high amount of CPU as well. If so this appears to be a bug in Mavericks. I am in the process of rolling back to 10.8 because my iMac was taking almost 10 minutes to copy/paste text.